# Use variable in jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this code

```
if($("input[name='staylogged']").is(":checked")){
        var staylogged = "yes";
        }else{
        var staylogged = "false";
        }

        var form_data = {
            username: $("#username").val(),
            password: $("#password").val(),
            staylogged
        };
```

but the var staylogged in form_data doesn't work as expected where is the error?

i don't know how to declare the var staylogged in form_data

Comment: Your variable staylogged is out of scope.  Move its declaration ( `var staylogged` ) outside the if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your staylogged variable is out of scope.  Try declaring `var staylogged` outside of your if statement.  You also need to give it a key.

```
var staylogged = ""; // give it a default value
if($("input[name='staylogged']").is(":checked")){
    var staylogged = "yes";
} else {
    var staylogged = "false";
}

var form_data = {
    "username": $("#username").val(),
    "password": $("#password").val(),
    "staylogged": staylogged
};
```

Answer (score 8):

Don't redeclare the `staylogged` variable multiple times. A variable should be declared only once within a given scope. Also when building your `form_data` variable try to write valid javascript:

```
var staylogged = 'false';
if($('input[name="staylogged"]').is(':checked')) {
    staylogged = 'yes';
}

var form_data = {
    username: $('#username').val(),
    password: $('#password').val(),
    staylogged: staylogged
};
```

or a shorthand using the `? :` operator:

```
var staylogged = $('input[name="staylogged"]').is(':checked') ? 'yes' : 'false';
var form_data = {
    username: $('#username').val(),
    password: $('#password').val(),
    staylogged: staylogged
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code inserts the value of `staylogged` where you've put it in the code. So your code basically reads like this:

```
var form_data =  {
    username: $("#username").val(),
    password: $("#password").val(),
    true
};
```

Which obviously doesn't make sense. You need to provide a key:

```
var form_data = {
    username: $("#username").val(),
    password: $("#password").val(),
    staylogged: staylogged
};
```

Object literals need key-value pairs. The name of the key isn't inferred from a variable name.

Answer (score 3):

```
 var form_data = {
     username: $("#username").val(),
     password: $("#password").val(),
     staylogged: staylogged
 };
```

This will result in `form_date.staylogged` being `yes` or `false`

Also i would recommend you set staylogged to `true` and `false`, it's easier to validate.

```
if($("input[name='staylogged']").is(":checked")){
    var staylogged = true;
} else {
    var staylogged = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you just want a field named `staylogged` that has the same value as the local one?  If so, then you still just need to assign it like normal:

```
var form_data = {
    username: $("#username").val(),
    password: $("#password").val(),
    staylogged: staylogged
};
```